# how to write while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I am currently making a simple ATM program in java.
I want to write a while loop where when user enters wrong pin it will prompt the user to enter again until the pin is matched. When the pin is matched, it will display the main menu.

I tried by myself, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
while(userPIN != savedPIN)  
    {
     System.out.print("Please enter your correct PIN : ");
     Scanner again = new Scanner(System.in);
     int pass = again.nextInt();
     break;
    }
```

Comment: You can use a single Scanner in the program. Its inefficient to keep recreating the scanner.

Comment: how to use a single scanner?

Comment: Create your scanner before the loop and just use that one.

Comment: Perhaps you need to assign userPin rather than pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `break;' statement and update userPIN with the new pin as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int savedPIN = 4444;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter password");
        int userPIN = input.nextInt();
        double withdraw = 0.0, amount = 0.0, deposit = 0.0;

        while (userPIN != savedPIN) {
            System.out.print("Please enter your correct PIN : ");
            Scanner again = new Scanner(System.in);
            userPIN = again.nextInt();
        }

        while (userPIN == savedPIN) {

            System.out.println(" 1 - Inquire Balance \n 2 - Withdraw \n 3 - Deposit \n 0 - Quit ");


            Scanner inputNum = new Scanner(System.in);
            int number = inputNum.nextInt();
            switch (number) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("The current balance is $" + amount);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Enter the amount to withdraw : ");
                    withdraw = input.nextDouble();
                    if (amount >= withdraw) {
                        amount = amount - withdraw;
                        System.out.println("The current balance is $" + amount);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Enter the amount to deposit : ");
                    deposit = input.nextDouble();
                    amount = amount + deposit;
                    System.out.println("The current balance is $" + amount);
                    break;

                case 0:
                    System.exit(4);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I did but it keeps asking me to enter the correct pin although I did.

Comment: This is what I did with your code and everything  seems to work, check the edit

Comment: Create only ONE scanner. Recreating or creating multiple is not necesarry, makes the code harder to read and increases memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Ok 2 errors:

1)you test `userPIN != savedPIN` but you accept the value into variable `pass` with which you do nothing.

2)remove the break in the first loop it will always exit without looping.

it should look like :

```
while(pass!= savedPIN)  
    {
     System.out.print("Please enter your correct PIN : ");
     Scanner again = new Scanner(System.in);
     int pass = again.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: I tried it but it keeps asking me to enter the correct pin although I entered the correct pin.